# Xcode doesn't show menus for build settings options

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, build-settings

I'm using OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks) and Xcode 5.0.2. I create a new project and in the project's Build Settings, there are no menus to choose values for the different options. Here's a screenshot...

[image]

You can see that, for example, Base SDK shows an `iphoneos` value, and Build Active Architectures Only shows the value `YES`, but it's like hardcoded, there's no menu to choose another value. Instead, when I create a new project in another computer, using also Mavericks (OS X 10.9 in this case) and Xcode 5.0.2, I get the expected menus, as seen in this other screenshot...
[image]

Why Xcode doesn't show menus for build settings options in one of the computers?

Comment: Have you tried double clicking it?

Comment: Double-clicking it opens a pop-up area where I can write any other value, and when I press Enter that new value replaces the old one. But that doesn't fix the problem (because, ex., in Code Signing Identity, I want to see a menu with the available identities).

Comment: Based on comments from the below answer and the one above I am completely confused at what you are after and what you think should be happening. Voted to close based on **Unclear what you're asking**

Comment: Popeye, it's clear. Notice how upper image does not have popup arrows on the value settings, while the lower image does? This is controlled by the `Editor > Show...` menu items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xcode, choose `Editor > Show Values`. That will switch from the current view style (which is "Show Definitions" that uses plain text fields) to using "Show Values", which will add in popup menus where appropriate.

Comment: This is still correct for more recent XCode versions (8.1+). An important note: the "editor->show values" option will only appear if the project settings editor is currently active. So, if you're viewing code for example, the menu option will be absent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all the available option for Build Setting then select All option and for Target setting option click on the Target option setting

[image]

Comment: The problem is not that I can't see all the available options, but that there's no menu to choose a value from for each option. Ex. notice that in my first screenshot the "Build Active Architecture Only > Debug" displays `YES` (in uppercase, **without** the symbol indicating that this is a menu to the right), whereas in the second screenshot it displays `Yes` (capitalized), **and** there's a symbol to the right indicating that this is a menu (as, in fact, it is, and by clicking on it I can choose between Yes, No, or Other...). Doing what you say doesn't change that (i.e. still no menus).